# Do past/present simple + infinitive invoke subjunctive mood?

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, present-tense

The construction *past/present simple + infinitive* is often used. Some examples are:

> — He **wanted** you **to come** with me.
>   — I **suggest** you **to do** this.

Questions:

1. Do these constructions invoke the subjunctive mood?
2. Can the above examples be rephrased?

Comment: The subjunctive [is often used](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html) after *to advise (that), ask, command, demand, desire, insist, propose, recommend, request, suggest, urge*, but it's not normally relevant to *need*.

Comment: When **need** is a synonym for **must** it can be so marked.  "Need they be placed so close to the window?"

Comment: I've changed my second example by using *suggest.*

Comment: The mandative subjunctive would look like this: "It is his desire that you come with me", IMHO.

Comment: Note that *suggest*, afaik, can't be used that way in standard English.

Comment: @DamkerngT. but FumbleFingers listed on the examples that you can use *suggest*.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! I meant we can't use *I suggest you **to** do this*. However, *I suggest (that) you (should) do this* is just fine.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I see. Can anybody provide an answer about this? It's interesting since in my language those constuctions are allowed.

Comment: I hope so! I think some of us can. I only have a very good idea how to use them (or maybe, how not to use them), but it's probably too shaky to turn my idea into an answer. Maybe I should pitch it a bit anyway. IMHO, "mood" is about "form", which is close but not identical to modality. (Some linguists argue that English has no mood, because in the so-called subjunctive mood, verbs don't change in form.) From a practical viewpoint, subjunctive is mostly used in mandative sentences, which is typically used with verbs FumbleFingers gave, and "It is important ..." like CopperKettle mentioned.

Comment: We *could* think of the subjunctive as any marking, including changes in the verb-phrase at the lexical level, that is meant to distinguish the utterance from the indicative and imperative.

Comment: @Subjunctive: You could probably justify starting a whole new SO site to list all possible contexts where "subjunctive" might be involved. But to my mind it's not very relevant to modern English anyway. Everyone likes to quote the example *The subjunctive is dead! Long live the subjunctive!* (where ***live*** is itself a subjunctive usage). But if that's not enough for you, the link I posted above goes into more detail. Your *suggest* example wouldn't be acceptable to many native speakers (but it'd be okay with *recommend*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, -recommend- works better.

Comment: @Damkerng T.: You probably know more than me about formal descriptions in this area, but off the top of my head I would have thought *I recommend you [**to**] do that* is still a "subjunctive" usage regardless of whether ***to*** is included or not. By which logic, *I suggest you do it* is also subjunctive - it's just that idiomatically almost no-one (except non-native speakers) would include ***to*** in that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He wanted you to come with me.

Not subjunctive; the "to" would be omitted in the subjunctive mood. You could rephrase to something close in the subjunctive: "He expressed his desire that you come with me".

> — I suggest you to do this.

This is somewhat uncommon, although I'm not sure it's officially wrong... I would use "I suggest that you do this" (subjunctive) instead. It can also be rephrased in the indicative mood, as "I advise you to do this". The difference is that you suggest something (optionally, to someone), but you advise someone (optionally, to do something).

Comment: It's interesting. All of these sentences trigger the subjunctive mood in my language.